# Accessing values from table connected by foreign key in flask template

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, jinja2

I am using PostgreSQL and Flask for my application. I set up all tables via PostgreSQL - not models.py.

So, I've got: users table, books table and book_reviews table.

Book_reviews have 'user_id' and 'book_id' as a foreign keys, as well as rating and review columns.

In my flask app I've got:

```
book_reviews = db.execute("SELECT * FROM book_reviews WHERE book_id=:book_id, {"book_id": book_id}).fetchall()
```

and then in template:

```
{% for review in book_reviews %}
   {{ review.user_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get user email, instead of his id here? 
If I used models.py to set up a database I could add a "backref" to a user field and that would solve the problem, right? 
How should I go about that in this case? Is there a way to add 'backref' in plain PSQL?

Comment: If your tables aren't defined in `models.py`, how will Flask know the relationship?  If that's the case, I think you would have to do a join between `book_reviews` and `users` tables, and include the `email` column.